# MSVC LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file “msvcprt.lib”

Tags: visual-c++, linker, lib, cl

I want to compile a cpp file with `cl.exe`
Command line: `cl main.cpp /Fe:test.exe /O2 /std:c++17 /MD`
But an error occurred during linking `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file “msvcprt.lib”`
It was normal before updating VS 2019 to 2022
And if I copy the libs to my root directory, it will be built successfully
I have added the directory to the environment variable `Path` like this:
[IMAGE:Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgPLw.png)

Comment: I just built the project requiring msvcrtd.lib and did not have any problems, however I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2020 Enterprise edition.
The path for the library should  be set when VS is installed. Maybe trying to reinstalling VS would help?

Comment: i can build it with VS2022 successfully,but now i want to use command line with cl.exe because it only have one file and don't need to create a new project and solution file.And before i updated VS 2019 to 2022,i could build it with cl.exe

Comment: I would not recommend this. What if you need to debug your code?
Anyway try to open cmd prompt and run VsMSBuildCmd.bat (or VsDevCmd.bat that is called from VsMSBuildCmd.bat) to set environment variables for VS 2022, then run your build command.
I guess you have your cmd set for VS 2019 variables.